# DBContext create to records on object insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking to find a good design for accomplishing the following.

In our C# MVC project using entity frameworks (and codefirst) we have, for sake of this conversation, 3 tables. Resource, Profile, Organization.

When we add a Profile record, we first need to create a Resource record, and using the ResourceId as the ProfileId. The same for adding an Organization.

I'm not sure if there is a good way to handle this. Right now we do something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostProfile(Profile profile)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var res = new Resource();
    _db.Resource.Add(res);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    profile.ProfileId = res.ResourceId;
    _db.Profile.Add(profile);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = profile.ProfileId }, profile);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are the models related in any way?  That is, if one is a child of another then can you create the aggregate root model and populate it with any child models and just save them all in one context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not atomic what happens if the second SaveChanges crashes for example because database doesn't respond,...

It's better to take a approach with just one SaveChanges()

```
var res = new Resource();
_db.Resource.Add(res);

profile.ProfileId = res.ResourceId;
_db.Profile.Add(profile);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

A part from this I think that is better to model objects in a different way, instead of having the ID of Resource in Profile, have the entire object, and the you can get advantage of lazy loading, a more powerful queries.

```
public class Resource()
{
     public int ID { get; set; }
     .......
}

public class Profile()
{
     public int ID { get; set; } 
     .....
     public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to add the new item

```
var profile = new Profile() 
{
    Resource = new Resource(),
     ....
}

_db.Profile.Add(profile);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Your first example works for us. In your second example... how do you define that the ResourceId is the same as the ProfileId?

Comment: Why do you need that the two objects uses the same key? They can use differents ID's and have a Foreing key in Profile table to Resource.

Comment: Not my design. Part of the requirements. I can go into details elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Profile` class needs the `ResourceId`, you may add a new property:

```
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The `virtual` keyword is to manage **change tracking** and **lazy loading**.

In your db context `OnModelCreating()` method link both fields:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasRequired(x => x.Profile)
    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ProfileId);
```

Instead on `HasRequired()` use `HasOptional()`, if required. More on this topic can be found at [MSDN - Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx).

Now you can add both objects in a single db operation:

```
var _profile = new Profile();
// set more _profile properties
_profile.Resource = new Resource 
                         {
                             // set resource properties, but
                             // exclude the Id property
                         };

_db.Profile.Add(_profile);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But where do I define that the ProfileId is the same as the ResourceId?